# Semantic Media Wiki not installed

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I was looking to install Semantic MediaWiki and found the link:[Semantic MediaWiki Installation](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aInstallation_1.9.x)

After installation, as given in the tutorial, I am not getting the SMW version on the Main Page I have created using the option of Special:Version.

MediaWiki is installed and displayed at the lower right (Powered by MediaWiki) but not getting the (Powered by Semantic MediaWiki) option that surely I will get after the complete installation.

Can somebody explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this matter deeper and has been working on it.
After following the link mentioned above, when you have done installing MediaWiki, please follow the link[Final installation of Semantic Media Wiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aInstallation_on_Windows)

and start from point 3 of heading: **Install / Update SMW with Composer**

Also, this link is also useful: [Repairing Semantic MeiaWiki's data](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aRepairing_SMW%27s_data)